# Column value of one table should be column headings when query is executed

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, dynamodb-queries, sqldb

I have two tables: **pet type**

| Id | TypeB |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | dog |
| 2 | cat |
| 3 | snake |

Then another **owners**

| Ownerid | Pettype |
| --- | --- |
| 001 | 1 |
| 002 | 2 |
| 003 | 3 |
| 004 | 0 |

I am trying to get the values those owners who have pets as in this format

| Ownerid | Cat | Dog | snake |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 002 | 0 | 1 |  |

It should display like this format I tried using joins but couldn’t can any one help me out

I tried using join of three tables

Comment: Moving values between rows & headings is pivoting/unpivoting. PS Please before considering posting read the manual/reference & google any error message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. Reflect research. [ask] [Help] [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/3404097)

Comment: Ownerid=1 should have Dog=1 and Ownerid=2 should have cat=1

Answer (score 0):

use `pivot` as follows

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
select Ownerid,TypeB from Ownerstable o
join pettype p
on p.Id=o.Pettype
) d  
PIVOT
(
    count(TypeB)
    FOR TypeB IN ([cat],[dog],[snake])
) p
```